# Updating tuple values in python

Tags: python

We can not update or modify tuple in python.
I am writting a code that is updating a tuple.

Why is it not giving any error?
Here is my code

```
tuple1=(1,'hello',5,7,8,)
tuple1=tuple1[1:3]*2
print tuple1
print tupele1[3]
```

Why is it showing the output  without any error?

> Output :('hello', 5, 'hello', 5)
>
> 5

Comment: What is the *desired* output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not updating the tuple, you're creating a new tuple with different values.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't *mutating* the tuple, you're **rebinding** the name bound to it. This is not restricted by Python.

```
>>> (1, 2, 3)[1] = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>> a = (1, 2, 3)
>>> a = 4
```

Answer (score 2):

We can not update values in a tuple,But we can reassign the variable that referer to a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

`*` does not what you think it does. It multipyls the *slice*, not its contents.

```
tuple1[1:3] == ['hello', 5]
tuple1[1:3] * 2 == ['hello', 5, 'hello', 5]
```